# How to find out which program add LANG environment variable besides system/current-user environments on windows OS?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I found there's a `LANG` environment variable with value `zh_CN` in environments (reported by `set`), but this variable **does NOT exists** in system-wide/current-user environments.

1. After reboot, the `LANG` environment variable does not exists yet.
2. After some operations, `LANG` will appear, and it affected environments of `explorer.exe` process (use procexp.exe to see environments of explorer.exe), hence, all new created child process will inherit environments of `explorer.exe`.
3. After edit any environment variables and save, `LANG` will disappear.
4. Repeat step 2, `LANG` does not appear anymore.

I can't figure out which operation in step 2 caused `LANG` appeared, but most likely, it's when right click a file and then menu popuped.

So, I *suspect* it's some shell extension programs add `LANG` environtment variable to `explorer.exe`. In the popup menu, there are the following shell extensions:

- 7-Zip 9.22 beta
- WinRAR 4.00
- gVim 7.3.46
- EditPlus v3.30 (v605)
- Notepad++ 5.9 (UNICODE)
- Git 1.7.4-preview20110204
- TortoiseCVS 1.12.2
- TortoiseSVN 1.16.16
- XnView Shell Extension 3.0.0 (XnView 1.98)

Most of these programs related to `LANG` environtment variable (GUI language), but which one? Is there a tool to monitor environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute-force method:

1. Open a Command Prompt, run `set LANG=` to remove the variable.
2. Download [ShExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and disable all extensions except one.
3. Close Explorer and restart from the previously opened Command Prompt.
4. Right-click a file, check if environment variable appeared.
5. If `%LANG%` appeared, finish. Otherwise, enable another extension and go to #3.

---

You can close Explorer by killing it through Process Explorer, but here's a "clean exit" method:

- Vista/7: *Start*, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, right-click on empty space, choose *Close Explorer*
- XP: *Start* → *Turn Off*, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, click *Cancel*
- older versions: *Start* → *Shut Down*, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, click *Cancel*

Comment: Thanks for the great ShExView tool, and the "clean exit" method, never known these before. And finally, it's **Vim Shell Extension** added the `LANG` environment variable. Cheers! I'll uninstall gVim and reinstall without it's shell extension, or just disable Vim Shell Extension by ShExView.

Comment: the related **Vim Shell Extension** code is here: http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/GvimExt/gvimext.cpp#286

Comment: @LiuYan: Or you could instead permanently set the variable to whichever value you think is correct, if `zh_CN` is not.

Comment: LANG environment variable is unexpected/unwanted. It affects Cygwin and others' environment.

Comment: It was Vim Shell Extension for me too.